# Visual Studio can't find any packages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, nuget

I've been trying to build a project repo'd in GitHub, I cloned it, opened it, tried to build it and it throws 2 errors and 63 warnings, all of them of viusal not being able to find any packages. 
The packages are there, in the package folder, I've tried deleting it and rebuilding, which downloads all packages again, inside the folder, and then proceeds to throwing the same errors again. Any suggestions?

[Visual Studio errors screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHRgH.png)

EDIT: Ok so, we made a new repo without the gitignore, that worked. Any clue of what might have been ignored that messed everything up?

Comment: I believe you've answered your own question. If you made a repo with the gitignore that didn't build and you made a repo without a gitignore that would build, wouldn't this insinuate that you were ignoring files (perhaps a configuration file)  or packages that were important to building the project?

Comment: 1) Perhaps the project referenced an assembly that wasn't obtained through NuGet -- the gitignore prevented that file from loading properly. 2) The second error in the list, at least for previous VS versions, was a bug which required new cloned projects to be closed and reopened before the packages loaded properly.

Comment: Yeah, I think you're both right, there is something ignored that seems to be vital, I just can't seem to find it, and leaving it without a gitignore and cloning excessively large projects is less than ideal.